# POWERPIVOT - DAX : ALL Function not working

Tags: filter, dax, powerpivot

Cannot find the answer to the below in the Internet:
I want to display all returns in pivot table regardless the pivot table filter context.

Quantity Returned:=SUM(Returns[quantity]).

AllReturns:=CALCULATE([Quantity Returned],ALL(Returns[quantity]))

With no filters , both measures should give me the same number of returns.

Returns table is as follows (table is not complete):

| Product Id | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 2 |

Pivot table shows as follows:

| Product Id | Quantity | AllReturns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 3 | 7 | 7 |
| 4 | 15 | 15 |

I woudl like AllReturns column to show 32 for the 3 rows. What is wrong in the measures?

Comment: ALL (Returns[Quantity]) only remove filters over the column [Quantity]. The column [Quantity] is not filtering the data model from the pivot table (row labels - column labels - slicers). You can use ALL(Returns) or ALL(Returns[Product ID]) as CALCULATE modifier.

Comment: Thanks,  it works with ALL (Returns)